# how to submit form after ajax response of submitting another form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that is a file input:

```
<form method="post" id='careerform' action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/career'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="cv" id="cv">
   <input type="button" id="submitcareer" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" value="Submit">
</form>
```

when the user clicks on submit, the form will be checked for validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

$('#careerform').bootstrapValidator({

        feedbackIcons: {

            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',

            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',

            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'

        }, 

        fields: {

    cv: {

        validators: {

            notEmpty: {

                message: 'CV is required.'

            },

            file: {

                extension: 'doc,docx,pdf,zip,rtf',

                type: 'application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/rtf,application/zip',

                maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,

                message: 'The selected file is not valid, it should be (doc,docx,pdf,zip,rtf) and 5 MB at maximum.'

            },

        }

        }
    }
    }); 
$('#submitcareer').click(function(){      

                $('#careerform').data('bootstrapValidator').validate();     

                if($("#careerform").data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()){
            $('#modalbtn').click();         

                }        

                }); 

});
    </script>
```

then a modal will appear, the modal contains a form that include google recaptcha inputs:

```
                <div class="modal-body">
<form method="post" id="modalform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <?php                       

                            require_once(Yii::app()->basePath.'/extensions/recaptchalib.php');

                            $publickey = "...";

                            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);

                        ?>                      

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalsubmit" >Submit</button>                 

                    </form>                   

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <script type="text/javascript">         

                        $(document).ready(function() {                                  

                                $("#modalsubmit").click(function(event){ 
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type:"post",
                                        url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('site/verify'); ?>",
                                        data:$("#modalform").serialize(),
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        async: false,
                                        success:function(response){

                                            if(response == 2){

                                                    $('#careerform').data('bootstrapValidator').validate();
                                                        if($("#careerform").data('bootstrapValidator').isValid()){      
                                                            $('#careerform').submit();
                                                        }

                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
                                });

                        });

                    </script>

                </div>
```

the ajax response will be 2 if the user entered the captcha correctly, then the first form should submitted.

my problem that is the first form is not submitted when I am getting a response value = 2, so what is the problem here? is there another way to do what I want ?

Comment: For a starter, what's the point of reCaptcha if it can be bypassed by disabling JS?

Comment: Change `$('#submitcareer').click(function() {` to `$('#submitcareer').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @mplungjan same result

Comment: @IbrahimAshShohail the form will not be posted to the server without the response result, so if you bypassed it, nothing will be happened

Comment: What is the server's response?

Comment: @MaxMeijer the server response is `json_encode(2)` if the captcha is correct or 1 if it is not correct

Comment: What do you get if you log `response` in the success function?

Comment: @MaxMeijer I got `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine which type is response. jQuery is trying to convert the response as a JSON object if dataType is set to JSON.

Comment: Thats not what i mean. Try console.log(typeof response). if it's object then it can't contain 2 as value. What is the server response?

Comment: just try the following then as response to check if this is a client problem: echo json_encode(array('type' => 2)); in your callback function just check response.type then.

Comment: Don't check the type, just check what's in response.type (expected -> 2). For your code: if(response.type == 2) { ....

Comment: Then it's an issue with the client behavior if the form is still not submitted. Look at the validator code to determine what's wrong

Comment: the validation process is called before the captcha form, everything is correct in the validation, but the form is still no submitting